# Adding references dynamically in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have two dll's (sqlite) , one dll is a 64 bit and other 32 bit dll. Is it possible to add reference dynamically based on processor architecture? P/Invoke is my last option. Any help would be appreciated!!

Sample Code:

```
string pathToDll = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\x64\\System.Data.SQLite.dll";
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(pathToDll);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(assembly.GetName());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditionally use 32/64 bit reference when building in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832552/conditionally-use-32-64-bit-reference-when-building-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Maybe it`s help to you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832552/conditionally-use-32-64-bit-reference-when-building-in-visual-studio/3833444#3833444

Comment: One may want to compile to Any architecture and run on both 32/64. Of course you can solve this by good installer, but this may not be a duplicate

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can load assembly from a file

```
 Assembly.LoadFrom("MyAssembly.dll");
```

from .net4 you may use Is64BitOperatingSystem Environment property. Otherwise check IntPtr.Size which changes according to running architecture

[Cannot encrypt / decrypt SQLite database in .NET4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535511/cannot-encrypt-decrypt-sqlite-database-in-net4/8535689#8535689)

Comment: How will I use the dll methods,since I will be dynamically adding reference?

Comment: I added a link to my other response which should help you

Comment: I read about the assembly.loadfrom method. It looks like the real deal, I'll confirm the solution tomorrow

Comment: I tried assembly.loadfrom method. It gets loaded but VS still throws exception. It still thinks that the file is x86 (on x64 machine)

Comment: A quick question, can I fake the System.Data.SQLite namespace to the compiler?